# Trouble with tutorial

Tags: ros, roscd, setup.sh, setup.bash, beginner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to linux, but I'm trying my best to deal with the terminal command line. I've finally got the right version of linux and ros diamondback installed in a virtual machine and I'm trying to work my way through the tutorials so I can eventually be able to port a control system onto a quadrotor. I've gotten to the "Create a Package" tutorial and I can't get roscd working. It returns "roscd: command not found". I did some digging and apparently the installations have changed some policy having to do with the difference between setup.sh and setup.bash:

> As of rosinstall version 0.5.12 it will no longer use bashisms in the 
> setup.sh file.  They have been moved to setup.bash.  And for zsh users 
> there is also a setup.zsh generated.
>
> For existing bash users this will mean that until you switch to use
> setup.bash instead of setup.sh you will not have the command line tools
> you are used to such as rosrun roscd and tab completion.

The tutorial only instructs me on how to create a setup.sh file. There is no setup.bash file in my tutorial directory so I can't just write setup.bash vs setup.sh in my bashrc file. Can anybody help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11768/trouble-with-tutorial/) by [ww3ace](https://answers.ros.org/users/1275/ww3ace/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2011-11-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Canelhas](https://answers.ros.org/users/1180/daniel-canelhas/) on 2011-11-02**:
Is there a specific reason why you're using diamondback instead of the latest version (electric)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! Strange, but I have setup.bash (ubuntu 11.04, Electric).

But I can say, that you don't really need in roscd/rosls etc. You can use standard linux commands, like `cd` or `ls`, with the same result (you only should to use full path to directory, e.g. 'roscd yourProject' vs 'cd ~/ros/yourProject'). It's not so comfortable, but it works!

If you really need in setup.bash - [here](http://pastebin.com/CQBk16c8) it is.

---

Originally posted by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) with karma: 546 on 2011-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

go to **/opt/ros/electric/**
and look for setup.sh
try to

```
sudo chmod +x /opt/ros/electric/setup.*
```

after that check - have you

```
/opt/ros/electric/setup.bash
```

in your **~/.bashrc**

---

Originally posted by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) with karma: 471 on 2011-11-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1